# Как собрать паттерн для поиска?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Самостоятельно учу Java, решаю задачи.

**Условие:**
*Ищем нужные строки
Считать с консоли имя файла.
Вывести в консоль все строки из файла, которые содержат всего 2 слова из списка words.
Закрыть потоки.*

**Пример:**
*words содержит слова А, Б, В*

**Строки:**
*В Б А Д //3 слова из words, не подходит
А Б А Д //3 слова из words, не подходит
Д А Д //1 слово из words, не подходит
Д А Б Д //2 слова - подходит, выводим
Д А А Д //2 слова - подходит, выводим*

Знаю, что можно просто через сплит сделать массив, потом сравнивать его элементы с каждым элементом списка. Но хочется решить при помощи регулярных выражений. Изначально, задумка была считать строку, убрать из нее все знаки пунктуации(\pP), а потом при помощи Pattern и Matcher найти нужное и инкрементировать счетчик. Но, чую, что напортачил при создании паттерна.

```
public class Solution {
    public static List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    static {
        words.add("файл");
        words.add("вид");
        words.add("В");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution s = new Solution();

        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s.fileNameReader()))){

            int count = 0;      
                   
            while (reader.ready()){

                String str = reader.readLine();
                str = str.replaceAll("\\pP", "");

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\bфайл\\b|\\bвид\\b|\\bв\\b)");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
                while (matcher.find()){
                    count++;
                }
                if (count == 2){
                    System.out.println(str);
                    count = 0;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    String fileNameReader() {
        String name = "";
       try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
           name = reader.readLine();
       }
       catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
^[^АБВ]*[АБВ][^АБВ]*[АБВ][^АБВ]*$
```

Тест https://regexr.com/590vk

```
В Б А Д
А Б А Д
Д А Д
Д А Б Д
Д А А Д
А икщьекищ342пи24т 245т4 щ42т ьщ24ть 4т6 Б В
А икщьекищ342пи24т 245т4 щ42т ьщ24ть 4т6 Б киштищштецшщтищшцтиц
```

Находит 4, 5 и последнюю строки.

Comment: Можешь подробно рассказать, что есть что? Я не очень понимаю это выражение.

Comment: @CilitBang `[^АБВ]` - любой символ кроме А, Б, В; `[АБВ]` - символ А или Б или В; `*` - повторение 0+ раз; `^, $` - начало и конец строки

Comment: У меня вопрос на миллион. А если мне надо не А, Б или В, а именно АБВ или БВА или АВБ?

Comment: @CilitBang `АБВ|БВА|АВБ`

Comment: т.е. (АБВ|БВА|АВБ) ?

Comment: @CilitBang ну да, если надо найти много штук, то `(АБВ|БВА|АВБ)*`. Если у вас уже какой-то новый вопрос, то лучше задать новый вопрос, а не спрашивать в коментах